# Using XSLT conversions in GeoNetwork to add XML nodes to metadata record during import

Tags: metadata, xml, geonetwork, xsl

I want to use "Apply XSLT converison" option in GeoNetwork when importing new records to add new XML snippet to my metadata record.

[image]

I need to add aditional XML content (gmd:identifier) to the following node: MD_Metadata/identificationInfo/MD_DataIdentification/citation/CI_Citation

The XML that I want to add looks like this:

```
<gmd:identifier>
  <gmd:RS_Identifier>
    <gmd:code>
      <gco:CharacterString>0105</gco:CharacterString>
    </gmd:code>
    <gmd:codeSpace>
      <gco:CharacterString>hr:nipp:hr</gco:CharacterString>
    </gmd:codeSpace>
    <gmd:version>
      <gco:CharacterString>1.0</gco:CharacterString>
    </gmd:version>
  </gmd:RS_Identifier>
</gmd:identifier>
```

The MD_Metadata/identificationInfo/MD_DataIdentification/citation/CI_Citation node already contains one gmd:identifier tag, new one needs to go below it.

I need XSLT code that adds the code to specified node.